# Parse JSON .txt file using RegEx in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I need help with understanding how to parse json text for my assignment, and I can't use JSON library as it is not permitted, hence only 're'.

This is part of the file (wrapped for legibility, originally it's all on one line):

```
{
    "unit": {
        "title": "Web Development courses",
        "raw_title": "{} courses",
        "source_objects": [{
            "type": "subcategory",
            "id": 8,
            "description": "Learn web development skills to build fully functioning websites.",
            "url": "/courses/development/web-development/",
            "title": "Web Development"
        }],
        "item_type": "course",
        "items": [{
            "_class": "course",
            "id": 625204,
            "title": "The Web Developer Bootcamp 2021",
            "url": "/course/the-web-developer-bootcamp/",
            "is_paid": true,
            "visible_instructors": [{
                "image_100x100": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/user/100x100/4466306_6fd8_3.jpg",
                "id": 4466306,
                "url": "/user/coltsteele/",
                "initials": "CS",
                "display_name": "Colt Steele",
                "image_50x50": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/user/50x50/4466306_6fd8_3.jpg",
                "job_title": "Developer and Bootcamp Instructor",
                "name": "Colt",
                "_class": "user",
                "title": "Colt Steele"
            }],
            "image_125_H": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/125_H/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "image_240x135": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/240x135/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "is_practice_test_course": false,
            "image_480x270": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/480x270/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "published_title": "the-web-developer-bootcamp",
            "tracking_id": "2zX-e8qKRUGgpwfF5AQx3w",
            "headline": "COMPLETELY REDONE - The only course you need to learn web development - HTML, CSS, JS, Node, and More!",
            "num_subscribers": 713744,
            "avg_rating": 4.6973553,
            "avg_rating_recent": 4.6947985,
            "rating": 4.6947985,
            "num_reviews": 215075,
            "is_wishlisted": false,
            "num_published_lectures": 610,
            "num_published_practice_tests": 0,
            "image_50x50": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/50x50/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "image_100x100": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/100x100/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "image_304x171": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/304x171/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "image_750x422": "https://img-c.udemycdn.com/course/750x422/625204_436a_3.jpg",
            "is_in_user_subscription": false,
            "locale": {
                "english_title": "English (US)",
                "locale": "en_US",
                "_class": "locale",
                "simple_english_title": "English",
                "title": "English (US)"
            },
            "has_closed_caption": true,
            "caption_languages": ["English [Auto]", "French [Auto]", "German [Auto]", "Italian [Auto]", "Polish [Auto]", "Portuguese [Auto]", "Spanish [Auto]"],
            "created": "2015-09-28T21:32:19Z",
            "instructional_level": "All Levels",
            "instructional_level_simple": "All Levels",
            "content_length_practice_test_questions": 0,
            "is_user_subscribed": false,
            "buyable_object_type": "course",
            "published_time": "2015-11-02T21:13:27Z",
            "objectives_summary": ["The ins and outs of HTML5, CSS3, and Modern JavaScript for 2021", "Make REAL web applications using cutting-edge technologies", "Create responsive, accessible, and beautiful layouts"],
            "is_recently_published": false,
            "last_update_date": "2021-09-09",
            "preview_url": "/course/625204/preview/",
            "learn_url": "/course/the-web-developer-bootcamp/learn/",
            "predictive_score": null,
            "relevancy_score": null,
            "input_features": null,
            "lecture_search_result": null,
            "curriculum_lectures": [],
            "order_in_results": null,
            "curriculum_items": [],
            "instructor_name": null,
            "content_info": "63.5 total hours",
            "content_info_short": "63.5 hours",
            "bestseller_badge_content": null,
            "badges": [],
            "free_course_subscribe_url": null,
            "context_info": {
                "subcategory": null,
                "category": {
                    "tracking_object_type": "cat",
                    "id": 288,
                    "url": "/courses/development/",
                    "title": "Development"
                },
                "label": {
                    "id": 8322,
                    "display_name": "Web Development",
                    "topic_channel_url": "/topic/web-development/",
                    "url": "/topic/web-development/",
                    "title": "Web Development",
                    "tracking_object_type": "cl"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_class": "course",
            "title": "etc",
        }]
    }
}
```

I have about 200 more lines like these, each filled with course/student etc etc info and I need to extract info from certain keywords from this json file.

For example, for course information, I need to extract course_id, 100x100 img, course_title, subscribers etc, and similarly for students, and instructors I need to extract some more information.

My questions are:

1. since the three classes (course, students, instructors) share some keywords like ID, how do I pull courseID, studentID, instructorID separately?
2. for course ID,
   I checked another link on stackoverflow and tried this but it didn't work so please help me out with this:

```
import re, os

raw_data_read = open('raw_data.txt', 'r')
regex_pattern = r'.*id\":\"([^\"]+)\".*'
match = re.match(regex_pattern, str(raw_data_read))
courseId= match.group(1)
print('courseId: {}'.format(courseId))
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but the person who gave you this assignment has no idea on how to do parsing and shouldn't teach this topic (at least like this). Using regular expressions on JSON won't work in many cases. Just imagine a `\"` in a string.

Comment: I mean… you could use regexen as a building piece for building a proper JSON parser…?!

Comment: it's an introductory python unit and we haven't been taught how to use regex either, it's been left to us to learn it ourselves and use it in the assignment @KlausD.

Comment: I hope the next lesson will be *"And this is why you never use regexen to parse JSON, as practically demonstrated by throwing you into the deep end."*